# settimeout javascript function - do they get cleared up when you navigate to different page

Tags: javascript

If I have setTimeout function that executes an ajax call every 5 minutes but then I navigate off the page to a different page on the same site before it has a chance to execute, will that ajax still happen when the timeout expires?

Comment: Open your console and check the network tab

Comment: Yes - it will be destroyed when you navigate away.

Comment: @Archer he asked if the function will still execute after leaving the page, the answer is ***no***

Comment: @Esko He asked 2 questions, one of which being if timeouts _"get cleared up when you navigate to a different page"_  I answered that and the answer is _**yes**_

Comment: I only see one question? ***will the ajax call in the callback function execute***? Well it's not super clear question :)

Comment: Guys guys it's sementics. I got the answered I wanted. JUst to check am not crazy. thankyou both.

Comment: @Esko - it's all good :)

Comment: Just refer to every single loaded web-page as a different sandbox / different PC. Your user hits F5 - poof, a server returns a new page, a browser renders a new page, the old one is gone.

Answer (score 0):

It will not execute if you navigate to another page using a classic **HTTP redirect**. If you are referring to an SPA(single page application) web app, then your JavaScript stack will continue and the your timeout requests will continue and their callbacks will be called.

This **status retaining** feature of SPA applications is a double edged knife, as it is really useful in some cases, but it can lead to memory leaks and multiple event bindings if asynchronous events are not handled correctly.

In your case, if you are not using some SPA framework like angular, react, ember or something similar, then, most probably, you should be using a classical HTTP redirect and your **timeouts will get cleared after each page load**.